# Угол между векторами в 3D от 0 до 360

Tags: математика, любой-язык

##### Как найти полный угол *(0-360)* между векторами `v0={x0, y0, z0}` и `v1={x1, y1, z1}`?

Обычный способ дает угол *0-180*.
Имею ввиду `acos(v0.dot(v1))`.

Я знаю, как найти полный угол между двумя плоскостями:
Находятся две нормали, и в зависимости от проекции нормали на нормаль (>0 или <0) либо прибавляется 180 к углу, либо отнимается. Но этот способ не получается применить.

###### Как можно решить проблему?

### UPD:

Я знаю, что второй отрезок начинается в конце первого. Отрезки всегда направлены как на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотря с какой стороны смотреть на пару векторов, угол будет или `x`, или `360-x`. Ваш метод как раз выдает меньший из двух углов. Расскажите, какую проблему вы решаете, может быть там есть еще какие-то входные данные, про которые вы не сказали.

Comment: После правки лучше не стало. Как определить, с какой стороны смотреть на вектора? С той, как на картинке, или с противоположной? В зависимости от этого будут два разных угла. Нужен как минимум третий вектор - "с какой стороны смотреть". И то это не всегда работает (если повернуть три вектора так, что все будут в одной плоскости, угол посчитать станет невозможно).

Comment: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/215103)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В пространстве нет выделенного направления, относительно которого можно посчитать углы более 180 градусов.

Такое направление (направленная ось вращения) может быть задано вектором, перпендикулярным к обоим векторам, но этих направлений два (векторные произведения `n1=a x b, n2=b x a`), поэтому без дополнительных ограничений задача не имеет решения.

Comment: Какие должны быть ограничения? Вектора направленные v0 = {a, b}, v1 = {b, c}, где a, b, c - точки. Тогда  же одно направление?

Comment: Именно так и есть. Как тогда измерить углы?

Comment: Я сейчас добавлю картинку в вопрос, станет понятнее, наверное.

Comment: Нет, вокруг векторного произведения углы будут не больше 180. Если поворачивать вектора, увеличивая угол, то при переходе через 180 градусов, векторное произведение разворачивается в обратную сторону.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, приём с осью как векторным произведением нехорош.

Comment: А если спроецировать обе вектора в плоскость?

Comment: @AntonAsperger  По картинке  - если вы смотрите на эти векторы спереди - угол один, а если "сзади экрана" - то другой. По плоскости - угол будет зависеть опять же от направления нормали.

Comment: угол между двумя векторами всегда величина в пределах 0-180 градусов. Остальное от лукавого.